# How to show ok button only in message box when there is not enough space to install application

Tags: inno-setup

In my current installer , i am getting an warning message when there is not enough space available in the hard drive where i am going to install the applications.
A message box appears showing  that continue installation anyway . Here i need to display OK button only instead of YES and NO button . Please help me on this issue.

Comment: The message box is displayed automatically when there is no space available in the hard disk . By default it has YES and NO button to continue or stop but i want to display a message with OK button and installer should not proceed further.

Comment: Please give me an idea how to solve the above issues. I am not able to hide the YES and NO button in the message box which comes automatically when there is not enough space in the hard disk.

Comment: There is no need for further comments repeating the question or asking for replies. Also not that that message MAY be wrong. It does the calculation based on what it is about to install, but if any of those replace existing files or delete others, then it will end up using less space. That's why it's not a fatal error.

Comment: This qustion was rephrased and re asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21774868/588306)