# When out of disk space, how to prevent Inno Setup from offering to skip a file?

Tags: inno-setup

When an Inno Setup installer runs out of disk space during installation (while actually copying files) it shows this error message:

[image]

**Is there any way to get it to omit the *"Skip this file ..."* option?**

I don't want users to do that, it would leave things in a random state and is likely to break the app at runtime. Better for the user to be forced to either make more space or cancel the installation immediately.

Looking in the Inno Setup documentation the only thing I can find related to disk space is
[`[Setup]: ExtraDiskSpaceRequired`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp//index.php?topic=setup_extradiskspacerequired) (or [here](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=componentssection)) but that wouldn't have any effect on this issue as far as I can tell.

---

I am aware that I can add some code to the installer to do checks for available space, etc. But it would be much simpler just to use the built-in feature if doing so is possible.

Also, even doing such initial checks wouldn't guarantee the space would still be available a little while later, especially for a long running installer. So there is no way around potentially having users receive this screen.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to tweak the built-in functionality to do what you want. That dialog box cannot be customized in any way without modifying Inno Setup itself.

The closest you can get is by checking the disk space on your own before starting the installation:
[How to check whether required space is available in the hard disk to install application using Inno Setup installer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21774868/850848)